# How do I get the free space of a phone's MMC flash card

Tags: mobile, hardware, diskspace

I want to get the size and free space of a phone's memory card via USB connection from a PC.

I use [PC suite](http://europe.nokia.com/pcsuite) connection.

This isn't a mobile application; it's a desktop application.   All I do is to open a connection between the application and the mobile, then copy the required files to a certain folder in the MMC.

Now I need to get the free space and total size in order to notify the user if his memory card is full and then stop transferring. Is there a function in CONA that will help me do that?

Comment: Please give some more info. What language are you using? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm Active Sync on WinMo shows this, on G1 its an attached drive and for Iphone this info is found in iTunes. Im assuming your using WinMo?